# SQL Server - Table\Column usage

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, statistics

Is there any way to generate table\column usage statistics?

I mean how often a given table\column was accessed by `SELECT` statements?

Answer (score 0):

No. [`sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx) and [`sys.dm_db_index_operational_stats`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174281.aspx) might give a partial idea though.

See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2008/10/30/what-is-the-difference-between-sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-and-sys-dm-db-index-operational-stats.aspx) for the distinction between the two.

Or if you are on Enterprise Edition you could have a look at [SQL Server Audit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280404.aspx)

Comment: I already did that. But as you said this is only partial information. I have tables with large amount of columns and I would like to apply vertical partitioning to improve performance - that's why I need to check which columns are used most frequently. There are to many DB clients to analyze usage from end user point of view so the profiler is probably the only option....

Comment: There's no way of doing this in Profiler either. Except if you were to capture every SQL statement and parse it with reference to object definitions. If you have a view `CREATE VIEW V AS SELECT C1 AS A FROM T WHERE C2 = 1` then profiler won't tell you that `SELECT A FROM V` uses columns `C1` and `C2`

Comment: You can always follow the view definition but probably there will be more situations like this one.